# How do I point the Windows Security prompt to a domain via batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, dns

I provide technical support for students and staff at a college campus and I'm trying to write a batch script that will somewhat automate the process by which students on Windows machines connect to our (Windows) print server (I'd like to do this for Mac and Linux users eventually, but that's another post in and of itself).

Currently, in order to connect, students must run the following command:

```
\\deskprint.someuniversity.edu
```

(server and school name changed) either through the run command (XP and Vista), the start menu (7 and 10), or the start screen (8 and 8.1). Upon doing this, they must then enter their university login and password, as well as the domain for the university's network (we'll call it **"taco"**). Then, finally, they must click on the printer for their residence hall and install the driver.

Although we have tutorials for printing from all types of machines and devices, many students have issues connecting and must contact us to get connected. In order to simplify this process, I have written a simple batch script that prompts them for their university login without them having to remember the command to get to the prompt. All the student must do is run the script from their desktop and enter their login information. The current script is posted below.

```
@echo off
start \\deskprint.someuniversity.edu
```

For the most part, this solves the biggest issue students have, which is remembering the process for connecting to the server, as each version of Windows does it slightly differently (in addition, no one can ever seem to remember the address for the server and often type things such as 'www' instead of '\\' and the like).

Although this makes things somewhat easier, students still often forget to append '@taco' (the university's domain) to the end of their username. As a result, Windows will not accept their login information and will not connect them to the print server.

What should I do (if it can even be done) to tell Windows to point to the correct domain rather than using the computer's name as the domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's possible to prefill the login so what about displaying the reminder in a message box:

```
@echo off
start \\deskprint.someuniversity.edu
msg "%username%" Don't forget to add @taco after your username, please!
```

Comment: Wow! That's actually a really great idea. It's simple enough that it should reduce the number of students that NEED our help by a few, at least (our freshman enrollment is up a crazy amount this year). Thanks again!